# What is the main thread and loop in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, program-entry-point, traceback

I'm asking this because of the traceback I get in Python.

So I wanted to know what does this mean in Python. What does *main loop* mean? What does *main thread* mean?

Comment: I've duped you to the canonical post on the error. If you are asking us to define an event loop and threading, then your question is too broad. I suggest you read up on [event loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop). The term *python main thread* readily leads to the [threading documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.main_thread).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Why too broad?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I edited the question